# Report's textbox function call from ControlSource not firing

Tags: vba, report, ms-access-2010

Firstly, here's a pic on my report in design mode:

[image]

The underlying query for the report returns values like so:

```
Allen    Nelli    3:A,5:B,7:A,8:A, etc.
Breton   Micheline    1:A,3:A,5:B,7:A, etc
Caporale    Jody    1:A,3:A,5:B,7:A, etc
```

I had to use a subquery to get the third field which concatenates the **number : letter** combinations.  These values actually represent day of month and designation to a particular shift in a schedule.  So basically, for a given month, each individual works the designated shift indicated by the day value.

The intention is to call a user defined public function named PopulateTextboxes(Value as String) to be called from the first textbox in the report from the textbox's ControlSource property.  The third field in the query is actually named Expr1 and that is being passed as a parameter to the function. The function is designed to populate all the textboxes with the appropriate letter designation: A or B or C or D, etc. The function itself is not being fired when I run the report.

The function is as follows:

```
    Public Function PopulateTextboxes(Expr As String) As String
'Each element of Expr should be a number followed by a colon followed by a letter: 10:A,12:B,15:C, etc.
Dim shiftData() As String
Dim Data As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim temp() As String
Dim txt As TextBox
Dim rpt As Report
Dim strCtrl As String

If Expr = "" Then Exit Function

If IsNull(Expr) Then Exit Function

shiftData = Split(Expr, ",")

If UBound(shiftData) > 0 Then
  'Make a 2D array
  ReDim Data(UBound(shiftData), 2)
  'Load up 2D array
  For i = 0 To UBound(shiftData) - 1
    If shiftData(i) <> "" Then
        temp = SplitElement(shiftData(i), ":")
        Data(i, 0) = temp(0)
        Data(i, 1) = temp(1)
    End If
  Next i

  Set rpt = Reports.item("Multi_Locations_Part_1")

  If UBound(days) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "days array not populated"
    Exit Function
  End If

  'Populate each Textbox in the Multi_Locations_Part_1 Report
  For i = 1 To UBound(days)
    strCtrl = "txtDesig_" & CStr(i)
    Set txt = rpt.Controls.item(strCtrl)
    For j = 0 To UBound(Data) - 1
      If Data(j, 0) = days(i) Then
        txt.Value = Data(j, 1) 'A,B,C,etc.
        Exit For
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
End If
PopulateTextboxes = Expr
End Function

Private Function SplitElement(Value As String, Delim As String) As String()
Dim result() As String

result = Split(Value, Delim)

SplitElement = result
End Function
```

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, what you have there would set the value of that field to the return of the function PopulateTextboxes, if this returns nothing then nothing will be there.  You need to call it when the report opens, but I am not sure it will work like that, I think you'll need to have separate fields for each text box, then just bind them to that, so name,op1,op2,op3,op4 etc.etc.

Comment: FYI, the function doesn't return anything, but even so, when I altered the function so that it did return something, the function still wasn't being fired. Interestingly enough, even when I don't call the function and simply set the ControlSource of the first textbox to just Expr1, then run the report, that textbox doesn't populate with the data.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you show the function code?

Comment: Sure.  I've edited the original post with the added function.

Comment: I've set a breakpoint within the function but since the function isn't being fired neither is the breakpoint being triggered.

Comment: Since I was having problems with the textbox named txtDesig_1, I created a new textbox and gave its ControlSource = Expr1.  That worked.  Then I changed it to = PopulateTextboxes([Expr1]).  Then I got a runtime error message saying "Invalid use of property".  This maybe a clue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to call your function from the `Format` event of the Detail section, so it will be called for each record.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Call PopulateTextboxes(Me.Expr1)
End Sub
```

If `PopulateTextboxes` is in a separate module, I suggest to pass `Me` as additional parameter for the report, so you don't have to hardcode the report name.

Also note that you need the `Set` keyword when assigning object variables, e.g.

```
Set txt = rpt.Controls.item("txtDesig_" & CStr(i))
```

Comment: I edited the function as advised.  I called the function from the Detail_Format as suggested, however, that isn't even being fired.  I put a breakpoint on the function call but it's not breaking there.

Comment: You must open the report in **Page Preview**, not in Report view, for the Format event to fire. Not sure if there is a suitable event for Report view.

Comment: Calling the function from Detail_Format is not acceptable.  The report must display in Report View.  I discovered another problem as to why the function wasn't being called in the first place. Now that that is fixed and I'm able to step through the code, I'll post a separate question on this forum about another new issue at hand.